# Structure of the Lips and potential Dermatillomania

Tags: mouth, dermatillomania

If you grip the inside of your lips between your teeth and allow them to move back through, you can feel many small, relatively tough structures within. What are these structures, as I compulsively bite at these to the point of removing them, and would like to know what they are in case biting them free is causing serious harm. Biting in through the outer surface of the inside of the lip reaches a fairly strong membrane/barrier, and biting into this barrier allows the aforementioned structure to slip through it into the mouth, where it can be bitten free.

[image: lips]

On this diagram I would say it appears to be either the orbicularis orbis muscle, or minor salivary glands. The muscle's separation from the main flesh of the lip and membrane between the lip and affected area seem to match up, but if these muscles are fibres then it is unlikely to be those.

Comment: I am having a lot of difficulty imagining (or reproducing) what you're experiencing or what you're biting away. Is it on the vermillion itself? the mucosal surface? The skin? Much more detail is needed. You might want to link to an image of the anatomy of the lips as well for clarity.)

Comment: The bites come from the inside of the mouth so I have to assume it is behind the mucosal surface, but I am not certain.

Comment: No problem, please let me know if there is any more information I can give :)

Answer (score -3):

Greetings !
               I'm also biting and pulling away with fine tweezers, a tubular structure which, when one centres - positions the teeth in the best position to enable crunching thru' the tubular structures.   There is an intitial bleed from the mucous skin layer, but this rapidly stops, leaving the 'crunching ' sensation, which produces not too much pain. And this is one of the key pointers in my approach... simply put, if the pain level is tolerable, then it's NOT a part of me !

With this in mind, might I suggest considering that the 'Tubes' are in fact 'Morgellon', derived transport means. My logic for this, is that:
1. The Saliva ' strands' one can see in the mouth, when looked at with a microscope, are in fact Morgellon ( Electro-Piezo or Electro-Chemical structured )

2. I force, ( here the pain, is evident ) behind the Tubular structure ( I call it Worm, for simplicity ! ) a needle ot fine tweezers, and work this up to a copper electrical house wire ( 2.5 mm ), for this provokes the 'Worm', to defend itself, by releasing a 'Silicon-type fluid, which binds the injury closed, and in the case of the cornewr of the mouth, restricts ability to widely open the mouth... [ As an aside, could there be a link, here , I wonder , to the reportedly minicsule 'mouth', said to be a characteristic of 'Grey' Aliens ? ?  Please don't laugh, ANYTHING , in this 'Brave New Worls 'is a possibility ! !

Hope some of this might give food for thought  !

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that this is not the average SE site. Here, [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/should-answers-without-references-be-immediately-deleted) are required, even if the answer has some correct information; otherwise it's unsupported opinion; answers here need to be based on evidence. The [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help section](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) will provide more information about the site, as will a quick look at the top voted answers and at meta. Again, welcome.

Comment: If appropriate sources cannot be provided (Scientifically backed), this answer stands in danger of being deleted.

Comment: @Phillip: Btw. Since you mentioned 'Grey' Aliens, they may be on-topic on [Paranormal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96086/paranormal) paranormal:)

Comment: @Phillip: For any microscope investigations of yours, and you'd like to review your findings, you may ask at Biology.SE.